# How to reassign values to variables in the shell module of loop execution

Tags: ansible

What I want to achieve：

```
cur_first_number = first_number.stdout
for ip in groups[group_name]
 // shell command  exec execution grep -e  "{{ ip }}" "{{ openssl_cnf_path }}" ||  sed -i "/{{ last_line.stdout}}/a\IP.{{ cur_first_number }} ...
 // When  sed -i "/{{ last_line.stdout}}/a\IP.{{ cur_first_number }}  is executed successfully    
    cur_first_number += 1
```

This is my ansible code,it retrieves the IP from the file, and inserts the line,for example IP.{{ number1 }} = {{ IP }},if the {{ IP }} does not exist

```
- name: Get the first number of the last line in [alt_names] from the file openssl.cnf
  shell: grep -w "\[ req_distinguished_name \]" -B 2 "{{ openssl_cnf_path }}"  | head -n 1 | grep -o "[0-9]*" | head -n 1
  register: first_number
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Insert new line(IP.* = *.*.*.*) to the next line of matching content
  shell: grep -e  "{{ item }}" "{{ openssl_cnf_path }}" || sed -i "/{{ last_line.stdout }}/a\IP.{{ first_number.stdout | int + 1 }} = {{ item }}" "{{openssl_cnf_path}}"
  with_items: "{{ groups[group_name] }}"
  ignore_errors: true
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shell script isn't going to be able to change the value of an ansible variable. The best option is probably to use an [`index variable`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#tracking-progress-through-a-loop-with-index-var) on your loop and compute the ip address using that value.

Something like:

```
- name: Get the first number of the last line in [alt_names] from the file openssl.cnf
  shell: >-
    grep -w "\[ req_distinguished_name \]" -B 2 "{{ openssl_cnf_path }}"  |
    head -n 1 |
    grep -o "[0-9]*" |
    head -n 1
  register: first_number
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Insert new line(IP.* = *.*.*.*) to the next line of matching content
  shell: >-
    grep -e  "{{ item }}" "{{ openssl_cnf_path }}" ||
    sed -i "/{{ last_line.stdout }}/a\IP.{{ (first_number.stdout | int) +
      count }} = {{ item }}" "{{openssl_cnf_path}}"
  loop: "{{ groups[group_name] }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: count
  ignore_errors: true
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Note that I've reformatted your shell scripts to be more readable, but they remain syntactically identical (except for the changes to make use of the new index variable).

---

Instead of using this shell script to make changes to your openssl configuration, you might want to consider the [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) module instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is a condition missing in my description that has been supplemented. What should I do if I need to perform the assignment operation only when the condition is supplemented

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow the question in your comment. To what condition are you referring?